# How to pass CI/CD pipeline stage which starts an API

Tags: python, docker, continuous-integration, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm trying to start an API in my last stage of a git CI/CD pipeline. That's done in Python through FastAPI/uvicorn, which runs inside a Docker container.

```
app = FastAPI()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=777, host="0.0.0.0")
```

Everything works fine, however, there is one problem. Since the API starts and then keeps running (as it should), the CI/CD stage doesn't pass once the API has started, but it just keeps running also. Therefore the whole pipeline can never reach the passed status.

How would it be possible to mark a CI/CD stage as passed, even though the underlying Docker container (and the Python script inside it) has not terminated, because it needs to keep the API running?

Comment: Usually you don't want the CI/CD pipeline to leave any running resources behind the scenes; when the pipeline is finished, everything should disappear. What is the use case for having the container run after the pipeline has finished? What is the reason for starting the API inside the CI/CD stage? (FastAPI has the built-in `TestClient` for running tests against the API without starting a listening server)

Comment: The use case is a API for a machine learning classification model, which is trained in previous stages of the pipeline, and to automate it as much as possible. The API should then be available until it's stopped and updated in a future build. You would simply start the API manually outside the CI/CD environment then?

Comment: Yes, the CI/CD responsbility is to build, test and make available for deployment (or in the case of continuous delivery, deploy as well). How the application runs in the production environment is separate from the CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: I guess limiting CI/CD to run code linting, running tests is sufficient. deployment has to be done in the production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some people coming here are also happy with **running the API under test as a service**. The following CI Pipeline works with Gitlab. However, it is ugly to debug this on the runner. Like many comments here suggested already, I would also prefer proper end-to-end testing on a staging environment. It can still be useful in some cases, and debugging is also less problematic, when you have shell access to jobs on the runner.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE

build_image:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA 
  tags:
   - k8s

test_image:
  stage: test
  services: 
    - name: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:16
      alias: db
    - name: $IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA  # api runs as service
      alias: my-api
  variables:
    POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD: $POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD
    POSTGRESQL_USER: $POSTGRESQL_USER
    POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: $POSTGRESQL_DATABASE
  image: alpine:latest # test script runs curl in alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add curl jq postgresql-client
  script:
    - "curl -s -X POST -H 'accept: application/json' 'my-api/items/?n=100&random=true'"
    - "curl -s -X GET  -H 'accept: application/json' 'my-api/items/' | jq '.[][].email'" 
    - "echo 'THIS test is a STUB, and the pipeline lacks health checks for services'"
  tags:
   - k8s
```